# Fazendo consulta em tabela especifica do WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Como faço uma consulta no WordPress numa tabela especifica, sendo ela: `wp_dd_spg_galleries`?

Já tenho o ID da galeria, tentei fazer esta consulta, mas não retorna nada:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_dd_spg_galleries WHERE id = ".$idGaleria;
$idGal = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($query));
```

Comment: Consegui galera, fazendo da seguinte forma: $idGal = $wpdb->get_results($query);
 Ser um analfabeto com WordPress dá nisso... rs

Comment: Ewerton, publique sua solução como Resposta completa, obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `$wpdb->query()` vai apenas retornar o número de colunas afetadas ou `false` se não acontecer nada, então no caso você deveria usar `$wpdb->get_results()`.

Recomendo também você usar `{$wpdb->prefix}` para pegar o prefixo do banco que nem sempre será `wp_`.

Além de que você usou o `$wpdb->prepare()` da forma errada, pois ele funcionar como `printf()` e é assim que ele vai escapar os dados.

Aqui a forma correta de fazer a sua consulta:

```php
$idGal = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}dd_spg_galleries WHERE id = %d", $idGaleria ) );
```